# MySQL and PHP - how to display only the first five rows?

Tags: php, mysql, select, limit, where-clause

I have a database that I am successfully querying to display all rows where the value of one field equals x. What I need to do now is ONLY display the first 5 records that meet that criteria.

Here is my sql query so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Overall_Pts, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB' ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC;");
```

I tried adding LIMIT 0,5 to the query (after DESC but before the ';') but then it wouldn't display anything at all.

Comment: Seems like adding limit should work.  What happens if you add limit and run the query directly against the server?

Comment: This should work `SELECT Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Overall_Pts, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB' ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC LIMIT 5;`, run this query in phpadmin and check results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you accidentally put in a period:

```
LIMIT 0.5
```

which amounts to:

```
LIMIT 0,0
```

or

```
LIMIT 0
```

Try putting in a comma instead like

```
LIMIT 0,5
```

or simply

```
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this   `$result = mysql_query("SELECT Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Overall_Pts, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB' ORDER BY Pass_Yds DESC LIMIT 0,5");`