# How can I get 5 records for each 'category' with one select in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `topics`:

```
ID title body ctg_topic_id ... 
1  aaa   bbb  1            ...
2  aa2   bb2  2            ...
3  aa3   bb3  1            ...
4  aa4   bb4  3            ...
5  aa5   bb5  3            ...
6  aa6   bb6  1            ...
.......
105 a105 b105 23       ...
```

How can I get 5 records for each `ctg_topic_id` by 1 select?

Comment: How do you want to choose the 5 records for each `ctg_topic_id` ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thank you for your comment. The newest ones 'created' column.

Comment: Check this post:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817103/mysql-and-php-how-to-display-only-the-first-five-rows

Comment: @Gabrielo Using `LIMIT` won't help here I'm afraid.

Comment: This is not easy to do in MySQL.  You may have to write a custom function to help you.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thank you very much. I was told the same by my cooworker.

Comment: One escape plan would be if the dates were all in sync across `ctg_topic_id`.  In this case, you could just restrict with a `WHERE` clause to arrive at the right number of records.  Or, if you were to add a counter to each `ctg_topic_id` group, then this would also simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL script for mysql will give you the first five of all cats.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ctg_topic_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ctg_topic_id from your_table) GROUP BY ctg_topc_id LIMIT 0,5
```

Via PHP. (i omit the PHP connection code)

First, get the list;

```
$stm = $pdo->preprare("SELECT DISTINCT cth_topc_id FROM my_table");
$stm->execute():
$cats = $stm->fetchAll();
$result = array();
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * my_table WHERE cth_topic_id=? LIMIT 0,5");
$query->bindParams(1,$cat);
$pdo->execute();
$result[$i] = $query->fetchAll();
}
```

This simplified code should produce a matrix containing N arrays (where N is the number of distinct cats) that contains an array of 5 elements of the result set.

I've not checked the code so any hints will be corrected thanks.

One problem is that LIMIT 0,5 will get the first 5 items, withot any logic. If you want to sort use ORDER BY for example by ('date') etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry, I'm getting "Subquery returns more than 1 row" in 'Sequel Pro'

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ctg_topic_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT ctg_topic_id from your_table) GROUP BY ctg_topc_id LIMIT 0,5 replacing the equals with the IN operand

Comment: Sorry, you're right, change to "IN" does make it work. Sorry, Yuri, one more, it gives me 5 records in total (LIMIT 0,5). Is it possible to give me by 5 records for every ctg_topic_id? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can try by using UNION in all subqueries. If you group subqueries and you limit them the union will do the job.

Comment: But this solution won't scale for an arbitrarily large (and potentially unknown) set of groups.

Comment: In that case he migth do the job with the server side language.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ctg_topic_id from something, GROUP BY ctg_topic_id....
```

it will select all the categories..

Answer (score 0):

You can not. You can do it with one query using UNION or read this [How to select the first/least/max row per group in SQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)